# How does index created on separate columns works internally?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-indexes

I have a table Employee which has 10 columns . In my query where clause i am using column1 and column2 . If i create index on both columns
i.e. column1 and column2 . Is there a possibility both index can be utilized ?

There can be two approaches :-

- Approach1: For first where clause index is used and for second where
  clause result return by first clause is further filtered without
  using second index
- Approach2: For first where clause index is used , get row ids. For
  second where clause index is used , get row ids and do intersection
  of both rowIds

How does index works here ?

**update:-**

If strategy for MySQL or Oracle is different then please consider oracle as DB

Comment: Are you asking about mysql or oracle?

Comment: Please see mine update

Comment: For Oracle possible duplicate to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149078/can-multiple-indexes-work-together). And yes such behavior is definitively highly dependent on the RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Oracle it depends all on the selectivity of the used where predicates.

In **case that one predicate has a high selectivity and the other low**, only one index will be used and the second predicate will be filtered on the table.

Here an example of the execution plan

```
 select * from tab where a = 250 and b = 2;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |       |     1 |   207 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TAB   |     1 |   207 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX_A |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("B"=2)
   2 - access("A"=250)
```

here the predicate on `A` return only few records(1, but predicate on B returns 501 rows) and only the index on column A is used.

```
select 
sum(case when a = 250 and b = 2 then 1 end) as cnt_ab,
sum(case when a = 250  then 1 end) as cnt_a,
sum(case when b = 2 then 1 end) as cnt_b
from tab2;

    CNT_AB      CNT_A      CNT_B
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1        501
```

In **case that both indexes are not very selective, but the combination of the predicates is selective** Oracle can used either *conversion to BITMAP index* or *index join*. Which access path is selected depends on the table statistics and optimizer settings. In my case I got the bitmap conversion and used [INDEX_JOIN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#5232)  hint to get the other plan.
Note that the index join is only possible if the query returns only the columns defined in indexes.

```
 select  * from tab where a = 105 and b = 23;
```

Predicate selectivity

```
select 
sum(case when a = 105 and b = 23 then 1 end) as cnt_ab,
sum(case when a = 105  then 1 end) as cnt_a,
sum(case when b = 23 then 1 end) as cnt_b
from tab;

    CNT_AB      CNT_A      CNT_B
---------- ---------- ----------
       200      21700     100000
```

**Conversion to BITMAP**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                           | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |       |   829 |   167K|   434   (1)| 00:00:01 |
    |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TAB   |   829 |   167K|   434   (1)| 00:00:01 |
    |   2 |   BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS       |       |       |       |            |          |
    |   3 |    BITMAP AND                       |       |       |       |            |          |
    |   4 |     BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS   |       |       |       |            |          |
    |*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN               | IDX_A | 21552 |       |    45   (0)| 00:00:01 |
    |   6 |     BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS   |       |       |       |            |          |
    |*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN               | IDX_B | 21552 |       |   190   (1)| 00:00:01 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("A"=105)
   7 - access("B"=23)
```

**Index Join**

```
 select /*+ INDEX_JOIN(a idx_a idx_b) */ a,b from tab where a = 105 and b = 23;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                  |   829 |  5803 |   235   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW              | index$_join$_001 |   829 |  5803 |   235   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN        |                  |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| IDX_A            |   829 |  5803 |    45   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| IDX_B            |   829 |  5803 |   190   (1)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("A"=105 AND "B"=23)
   2 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
   3 - access("A"=105)
   4 - access("B"=23)
```

Answer (score 0):

(MySQL)

The "rowid" approach is very rare in MySQL.  This is probably because the `PRIMARY KEY` is used for such, and it goes directly to the row(s).

You are asking about a "composite" index of, say, `INDEX(a, b)`

```
WHERE a=1 AND b=2  -- Good index
WHERE b=1 AND a=2  -- Good index  (order does not matter _in the WHERE_)
WHERE a=1 AND b>2  -- Good index
WHERE b=1 AND a>2  -- Will ignore `b` in the index, but still use `a`
```

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Where row-id might be used:   http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1 , but less efficient than a composite index.